# How to report on a neovim issue

Tags: neovim

Under `nvim 0.8.3` typing in the `:Bwipeout` command when in an "empty" buffer, the following error message is displayed:

```
Error detected while processing the following function <SNR>53_bdelete
E684: list index out of range: 0
E121: undefined variable: back
```

The `:verbose func <SNR>53_bdelete` command shows me the function source code.

Sorry but I cannot find anyway to select on the source code so as to copy and paste a chunk of it. Doing a mouse click on the source code closes the display. Very frustrating.

How to find additional information on this or how to report an issue on this ?

Comment: That was quick.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report the issue to the nvim bugtracker on GitHub: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues

I have nvim 0.8.3 installed on Linux, but running `nvim` and running `:bwipeout` immediately does not produce errors for me, so it is better if you specify more details about your setup (operating system, how you installed nvim and so on) and exact steps to reproduce when you report the issue.